# $scope.search is undefined. Please spot the error. [object Object ] appears on textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

html tile

```
<form ng-submit="search()" name="searchcar"> 
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Chassis" ng-model="chassis" name="chassis" class="search_chassis_txt">
<input type="submit" value="" class="search_chassis" style="z-index: 2">
</label>
</form>
```

in controller.js

```
$scope.search = function(){
    if($scope.searchcar.$pristine){
        alert('Nothing to search.');
    }else{
        data = {
            'chassis': $scope.searchcar.chassis,
        };          
        $ionicLoading.show({template:'Searching....'});
    }
};
```

I have this error message that show:
Error: $scope.searchcar is undefined. On the same line as `$scope.searchcar.$pristine`

Thanks.

After updating ng-model to searchcar.chassis, the value [object Object] appear on my textbox by default.

What is causes the text to appear?

Comment: seems like it shoule be `searchcar.chassis` in _ng-model_ attribute

Comment: Can you add HTML where you assign ngController attribute?

Comment: @dfsq my controller attribute is defined in app.js.

Comment: @davidlee can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? your sample seems to work : http://plnkr.co/edit/4RbD0nY94klqYT2yT2Cr?p=preview

Comment: also what angular version you use?

Comment: I mean the problem is with placement `ng-controller` in HTML. It matters. Without seeing HTML it's hard to help. Otherwise check HaukurHaf's answer, even thought explanation of the problem is incorrect, the solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the form itself is not created in the scope.

Pass the form as an argument to the search method:

```
<form ng-submit="search(searchcar)" name="searchcar">
```

Then change the method accordingly:

```
$scope.search = function(searchcar){
    if(searchcar.$pristine){
        alert('Nothing to search.');
    }else{
        data = {
            'chassis': searchcar.chassis,
        };          
        $ionicLoading.show({template:'Searching....'});
    }
};
```